# getServerSideProps of a dynamic route triggered when calling a predefined route of the same level

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have a dynamic route page in the root of the pages directory - [userId].tsx .
I also have additional pages in the same level - sign-in.tsx, chats.tsx, etc...

Every time I render a predefined page (example.com/chats or something like that...) the getServerSideProps function of the [userId].tsx page is triggered. even though the rendered page is the correct one.